# Catch custom error and send back a custom response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Most often I come accross this problem where I throw a custom error from `middlewares` or from `services`.
I want to catch this custom error and send back a well formatted response like below.

```
{
  "error" : {
         "status":422,
         "message": "Please upload a jpeg or png file!"
    }
 }
```

*Middleware*

```
const multer = require('multer')
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const config = require('config')


aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: config.get("aws_secret_access"),
    accessKeyId: config.get("aws_access_key")
  });

const s3 = new aws.S3()


//accept only jpeg and png files
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(new Error('Invalid Mime Type, only JPEG and PNG'), false);
    }
  }

const upload = multer({
    fileFilter,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 *5
    },
    storage: multerS3({
      s3:s3,
      bucket: config.get("bucket"),
      acl: 'public-read',
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now().toString())
      }
    })
  })

module.exports  = upload
```

*Router*

```
router.post('/personal-detail', verify, upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {

    if(req.fileValidationError) {
        return res.end(req.fileValidationError);
  }
    //validate data before creating user
    const { error } = validatePersonalDetail(req.body)
    if (error) return res.status(400).send({ error: { status: 400, message: error.details[0].message } })
    //create user
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: req.user.id } })
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).send({ error: { status: 400, message: "User not found. Pleae register." } })
        } else {
            const personal_detail = await fillPersonalDetail(req, res)
            const result = _.omit(personal_detail, ['id'])
            return res.status(201).send(result)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).send({ error: { status: 500, message: "Something went wrong." } })
    }
})
```

I want to catch the error of the invalid mimetype.
I also have a error middleware.

```
//Handle any error
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // Do logging and user-friendly error message display
    logger.log({
      level:'error',
      message:err.message
    })
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send({error:{status:500, message: 'Something went wrong!'}}); 
})
```

What I want to is to modify this middleware in such a way that If it's custom error then it should send the message as defined, otherwise response "Something went wrong".

Something like below.

```
//Handle any error
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

    if(err typeOfCustomError) {
        return res.status(err.status).send(err.message)
     }
    // Do logging and user-friendly error message display
    logger.log({
      level:'error',
      message:err.message
    })
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send({error:{status:500, message: 'Something went wrong!'}}); 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve it. I created a `customError` that extends the `Error`.

```
'use strict'

class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor(message = 'Something went wrong!', status) {
        super(message)

      this.name = 'CustomError';
      // Custom debugging information
      this.message = message;
      this.status = status;
    }
  }

  module.exports = CustomError
```

In my midleware I simply check the type of error.

```
//Handle any error
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   // Do logging and user-friendly error message display
   logger.log({
    level:'error',
    message:err.message
  })

  if (err instanceof customError) {
    res.status(err.status).send({error:{status:err.status, message: err.message}});
  } 
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send({error:{status:500, message: "Something went wrong!"}}); 
})
```

Simple!
The down side with this method is that I have to do `require('../services/customError')` everywhere, if anyone have a solution please do comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use next() then it will switch in your middleware then you can pass every custom message from there.

```
router.post('/personal-detail', verify, upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {

    if(req.fileValidationError) {
        return res.end(req.fileValidationError);
  }
    //validate data before creating user
    const { error } = validatePersonalDetail(req.body)
    if (error) return res.status(400).send({ error: { status: 400, message: error.details[0].message } })
    //create user
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: req.user.id } })
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).send({ error: { status: 400, message: "User not found. Pleae register." } })
        } else {
            const personal_detail = await fillPersonalDetail(req, res)
            const result = _.omit(personal_detail, ['id'])
            return res.status(201).send(result)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        next(err)
    }
})

//Handle any error
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send({error:{status:500, message: 'Something went wrong!'}}); // Any custom error. 
})
```

Comment: The problem with this approch is how will you decide what message for which type of  error? I might have validation error, authorization error and others.

Comment: this is for common error like something went wrong please try after some time like this.

Comment: Otherwise, you should have to define the error code for sending any specified error msg.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = errorHandler;

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    switch (true) {
        case typeof err === 'string':
            // custom application error
            const is404 = err.toLowerCase().endsWith('not found');
            const statusCode = is404 ? 404 : 400;
            return res.status(statusCode).json({ message: err });
        case err.name === 'UnauthorizedError':
            // jwt authentication error
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
        default:
            return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
}
```